# Check if Many to Many exists in django?

Tags: django

I have two models,

```
Model University:
      name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
Model Students:
      name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
      wishlist = models.ManyToManyField(University, blank=True)
```

Basically this is wishlist, user can add university to their wishlist and if the reclick on the heart icon i need to remove the wishlist:

Here is my code:

```
   student = request.user.student
   university = University.objects.get(id=pk)
   if university.student_set.exists():
       student.wishlist.remove(university)
   else:
       student.wishlist.add(university)
```

So when, user1 added university1 to wishlist, then user2 couldnt able to add university1 to the wishlist, i dont know where is the mistake !Pleas guide, any students can add any university to their wishlist (its the requirement)

I think the problem is with the if statment

Comment: You don't need to check the existence, just use the ***`add(...)`*** method. If the object existing in the relation, Django will silently ignore the operation. But, using add() on a relation that already exists won’t duplicate the relation, but it will still trigger signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can prevent fetching the related student of the user in case we want to remove the university from the wishlist. This is usually more safer since a `User` that has no related student will then not raise an error:

```
university = University.objects.get(id=pk)
if university.student_set.filter(user=request.user).exists():
    Student.wishlist.through.objects.filter(
        university=university,
        student__user=request.user
    ).delete()
else:
    request.user.student.wishlist.add(university)
```

We can slightly boost efficiency in the `.remove(...)` path by not fetching the `.student` of the user, and thus implement this as:

Comment: I couldnt understand, can you please ellobrate ?

Comment: Why we are passing request.user instead of students ?

Comment: @sixovov947: with `university.student_set.exists()` you simply check if there is *at least one student* that has that university in the wishlist. But that is not per se the logged in user. We thus should filter such that we check if the logged in user has the university in the wishlist.

Comment: @sixovov947: we pass the user because we filter with `user=request.user`. This is usually more safe: if the user has no related student, then the check will simply return an empty queryset. But you can indeed filter with `.filter(pk=student)`. The two are equivalent.

Comment: Amazing, thank for the guide ! Have changed the code according to your suggestion :) and its working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

```
university.student_set.exists()
```

This doesn't check for any specific student. It should be:

```
university.student_set.filter(id=student.id).exists()
```

So overall this condition will be :

```
student = request.user.student
university = University.objects.get(id=pk)
if university.student_set.filter(id=student.id).exists():
   student.wishlist.remove(university)
else:
   student.wishlist.add(university)
```